# Extra margin being added for unknown reason

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have a form and there is a weird extra margin, would appreciate any help in finding why it is so.

Here is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/cc0k1ug5/#&togetherjs=R9HI9bogml

**HTML**

```
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="home-header" name="header-text">
  <div class="row">
    <h1 class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 main-title">Play to Learn</h1>
    <form class="form-horizontal form-card col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-12" role="form">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-12">
          <input type="text" ng-model="user.username" class="form-control" id="inputUsername" placeholder="Username">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-12">
          <input type="email" ng-model="user.email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-12">
          <input type="password" ng-model="user.password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-12">
          <input type="password" ng-model="user.verifyPassword" class="form-control" id="inputVerifyPassword" placeholder="Verify Password">
        </div>
      </div>
      <button ng-click="register(user)" class="btn btn-default col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10">
        Register</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
  .home-header {
  /*background: #f6512b;*/
  background: linear-gradient(#F6882E, #F25950);
  /*background: linear-gradient(#23A8C6, #5F6EB3);*/
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 5%;
  padding-top: 5%;
  width: 100%;
}

.form-card {
  padding: 2% 2% 2% 2%;
  background: #F8F8F8;
  border-radius: 1%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
  max-width: 35%;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}

.main-form-field {
  margin-left: 5%;
  max-width: 75%;
}

.main-title {
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.form-group {
  display: block;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Below class adding `padding`, remove it.

```
.container-fluid {
    padding-right: 15px;
    /* padding-left: 15px; */
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that bootstrap uses css rule like `.container-fluid > .row` to fix the padding, and when you insert additional layer of `div` you broke it.

If you replace your

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="home-header" name="header-text">
    <div class="row">
    ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

with

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row home-header">
  ...
  </div>
</div>
```

you will have your fix for free without messing with bootstrap-created css rules.